# Solving inhomogeneous differential equation with Green function

Tags: boundary-conditions, greens-functions

I'm not sure if this question is for physics forum, but my book's title is "Green's Functions in Quantum Physics", so I ask here.

The book says that the Green's function defined as

$$
(z-L( \mathbf{r}))G(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r'};z)=\delta(\mathbf{r-r'})
$$
solves the inhomogeneous differential equation 
$$
(z-L( \mathbf{r}))u(\mathbf{r})=f(\mathbf{r})
$$
with the "same boundary condition" and it gives the solution
$$
u(\mathbf{r})=\int d\mathbf{r'}G(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r'};z)f(\mathbf{r'}).
$$

I think that the third equation is just from by multiplying $f{(\mathbf{r})}$ to first equation and integrating it.

But then, why do we need the statement "with same boundary condition"? I don't see where to use that condition. My book does not prove this and wikipedia link [Green function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function#Framework) also states this, but no proof. Is there any simple explanation or proof for this?

Comment: Better on Maths SE

Answer (score 3):

Suppose for simplicity that $u(\boldsymbol{r})$ satisfies the boundary condition $u(\boldsymbol{r}_0)=0$ for $\boldsymbol{r}_0$ in the boundary then the integral on the right hand side of your last equation should satisfy

\begin{equation}
 \int{d\boldsymbol{r}'G(\boldsymbol{r}_0,\boldsymbol{r}';z)f(\boldsymbol{r}')}=0
\end{equation}

and then $G(\boldsymbol{r}_0,\boldsymbol{r}';z)=0$ it is, $G$ satisfies the same boundary condition as $u$. The same is true for Neumman boundary conditions.